# AJAX POST to controller not working in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to post post an id to one of my controllers and what I have is not working and I don't know why :

Route :

```
 Route::post('/save-book','UploadController@save_book')->name('savebk');
```

Controller :

```
public function save_book(Request $request)
    {

        dd($request->all());

    }
```

In the view :

```
<a id="bksv" data-value="{{$uploads[0]->id}}" href="" >Save it!</a>
```

jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#svd").click(function(e){
         var data = $("#bksv").data().value;
         console.log(data);

         $.ajax({
             url: 'save-book',
             data: {'id': data},
             type: 'POST',
             datatype: 'JSON',
             success: function (response) {

             },
             error: function (response) {

             }
         });

     });
  });
```

Can someone help troubleshoot? I don't know what is wrong in what I have.
I think that what I want to achieve is obvious.
In the controller I have a database query, which I deleted for this question.

The problem is : when I click the `<a>` tag basically nothing happens apart from the `value` being console logged.

Comment: change url to `/save-book` open network tab on browser and check whats happening when you press Save

Comment: tried it, but don't see anything from this url there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Some solutions**: maybe you have an error `$.ajax` its not a function which means that you are using a minified version of jquery so `$.ajax` its removed on that minified version. So make sure you include the uncompressed jquery version on top of the script:

```
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
      crossorigin="anonymous">
   </script>
```

**So your solution**:  NOTE: you have a TYPO  `$("#svd").click(function(e)` `id` its `bksv` NOT `svd` so this is working:

```
<a href="#"  id="bksv" data-value="32">Save it!</a>


<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#bksv").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
         var data = $("#bksv").data().value;
         console.log(data);

         $.ajax({
             url: 'save-book',
             data: {'id': data},
             type: 'POST',
             datatype: 'JSON',
             success: function (response) {

             },
             error: function (response) {

             }
         });

     });
  });
</script>
```

Try this in your controller

```
public function save_book( )
{

        dd(request()->all());

}
```

and make sure your url on ajax is `/save-book`

**Final solution** Since this is a post request make sure you include csrf token on request otherwise you will not be able to talk to the backend so in your html form add this field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

then on your ajax call data payload include that like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#bksv").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
         var data = $("#bksv").data().value;
         console.log(data);

         $.ajax({
             url: '/save-book',
             data: {'id': data, "_token": $('#token').val()},
             type: 'POST',


             success: function (response) {

             },
             error: function (response) {

             }
         });



     });
  });
```

Comment: now I was able to see the save-book in the network tab, but it shows status '405' "method not allowed". Do you know why is taht?

Comment: Tried it, but the problem still persists

Comment: @RobertRoss check last section of answer. Everything is tested locally and its working.

Comment: @RobertRoss You also have to pass the CSRF token with the request. You can pass it in the data attribute as `_token: {{ csrf_token() }}`

Comment: @GoogleMac thats an option, just wanted to make sure he has a csrf token in the blade aswell for other submissions.